# using groovy RegEx to grabbing values of attribute: code from grails message tag

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

I have parsed a gsp file into String and then i want to retrieve all values of the attribute "code" from grails message tag (including ${message...) as following:

```
deployment.order.label  
no.using.xx.label  
default.button.start.label
```

I have tried a lot by matching this with code="value" | code='value' | code: 'value' | code: "value" in RegEx, but still not working. can some RegEx expert help me out? thanks.

```
this is a start 
<g:message code="deployment.order.label" default="Definition order" />
dddfg fgfr
${message(code: "no.using.xx.label", default: 'Start')}"
this is a usf
<g:actionSubmit class="start" id="start" 
value="${message(code: 'default.button.start.label', default: 'Start')}" action="start"/>
kkkkk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex will be like this:

```
/(?:code(?:[=:])\s*?\\?(?:["']))([\w+\.]+)*(?:["'])/ig
```

1. (?:code(?:[=:])\s*?\?(?:["'])) - match word code with all variation
   of quotes.
2. ([\w+\.]+)* - match your value
3. (?:["']) - match closed quotes

Hope this will help.

The test script in perl will be like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;

$subject = "this is a start 
<g:message code=\"deployment.order.label\" default=\"Definition order\" />
dddfg fgfr
{message(code: \"no.using.xx.label\", default: \'Start\')}\"
this is a usf
<g:actionSubmit class=\"start\" id=\"start\" 
value=\"{message(code: \'default.button.start.label\', default: \'Start\')}\" action=\"start\"\/>
kkkkk";

my @matches;
push @matches, [$1, $2] while $subject =~ /(?:code(?:[=:])\s*?\\?(?:["']))([\w+\.]+)*(?:["'])/ig;

print Dumper(\@matches);
```

Comment: Thanks. i would take this solution. i adapt it in groovy way: def pattern3=/(?:code(?:[=:])\s*?\\?(?:["']))(\s*[\w+\.]+\s*)*(?:["'])/

  def msgs = content.findAll(pattern3){match, code->code.trim()}

Answer (score 1):

Only grabbing the value of the code:

Full expression: `/(?<=code[=:]\s?["'])([\w.]+)(?=["'])/`

`(?<=code[=:]\s?["'])` using a positive lookbehind, assert the presence of this expression but don't include in results

`([\w.]+)` get the text

`(?=["'])/)` using a positive lookahead, again assert presence of this expression but exclude from results

```
def str = '''this is a start <g:message code="deployment.order.label" default="Definition order" />
dddfg fgfr
${message(code: "no.using.xx.label", default: 'Start')}"
this is a usf
<g:actionSubmit class="start" id="start"
value="${message(code: 'default.button.start.label', default: 'Start')}" action="start"/>
kkkkk'''

def group = ( str =~ /(?<=code[=:]\s?["'])([\w.]+)(?=["'])/)

assert 3 == group.count
assert 'deployment.order.label' == group[0][0]
assert 'no.using.xx.label' == group[1][0]
assert 'default.button.start.label' == group[2][0]
```

Comment: Thank you. it's a simple and fine solution. for my case there is still one question. if i need to meet the case like more than one spaces before grabbed "Text"(e.g. code: [space space...] "text". i changed your solution with a quantifier to /(?<=code[=:]\s*["'])([\w.]+)(?=["'])/ and there is an compile error: "Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length." if I changed it to fixed width of space: /(?<=code[=:]\s{0,20}["'])([\w.]+)(?=["'])/ and it works. it seems it supports no variable length of quantifier in Look-behind. do you have compatible solution for this case?